# Time Complexity of list flattening

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two functions, both of which flatten an arbitrarily nested list of lists in Python.

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of both, to see which is more efficient, but I haven't found anything definitive on SO anything so far. There are lots of questions about lists of lists, but not to the nth degree of nesting.

### function 1 (iterative)

```
def flattenIterative(arr):
    i = 0

    while i < len(arr):
        while isinstance(arr[i], list):
            if not arr[i]:
                arr.pop(i)
                i -= 1
                break
            else:
                arr[i: i + 1] = arr[i]
        i += 1
    return arr
```

### function 2 (recursive)

```
def flattenRecursive(arr):
    if not arr:
        return arr

    if isinstance(arr[0], list):
        return flattenRecursive(arr[0]) + flattenRecursive(arr[1:])
    return arr[:1] + flattenRecursiveweb(arr[1:])
```

My thoughts are below:

#### function 1 complexity

I think that the time complexity for the iterative version is `O(n * m)`, where `n` is the length of the initial array, and `m` is the amount of nesting. I think space complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the initial array.

#### function 2 complexity

I think that the time complexity for the recursive version will be `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the input array. I think space complexity of `O(n * m)` where `n` is the length of the initial array, and `m` is the depth of nesting.

#### summary

So, to me it seems that the iterative function is slower, but more efficient with space. Conversely, the recursive function is faster, but less efficient with space. Is this correct?

Comment: The final flattened list is going to be of length `O(n*m)`, right? So any algorithm that returns a list (rather than a lazy iterator) pretty much _has_ to be at least `O(n*m)` space.

Comment: Also, you seem to be counting things like deleting and inserting into the middle of a list, or concatenating two lists, or copying the tail of a list, as constant-time steps. But each one of those actually takes `O(p)` work for a list of length p.

Comment: By the way, If you know how to write the `yield from flatten(elem)` lazy recursive version, you may want to try to analyze that first, because it may easier to work through—no list shifting or concatenating operations, no temp storage besides the stack, just counting up `O(1)` steps.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about `O(p)`. Are you talking about something like: 
`def iter_flatten(iterable):
  it = iter(iterable)
  for e in it:
    if isinstance(e, list):
      for f in iter_flatten(e):
        yield f
    else:
      yield e`?

Comment: Think about it this way: Python lists are just arrays, right? And after you pop element 1, the old element 8 is now element 7, which means it must have been moved. So a `pop(i)` with arbitrary `i` potentially moves every element in the list. In practice, the constant factor on this kind of bulk move of a bunch of contiguous elements can be so low that it's often the best choice, but you're looking at algorithmic complexity, not real-world performance.

Comment: And yes, `iter_flatten` is what I'm talking about—except that if you're using Python 3.3+ you can just do `yield from iter_flatten(e)` instead of `for f in iter_flatten(e): yield f`.

Comment: One more thing: It may be easier to work out the complexity in terms of the length of the final list (i.e., the total number of elements) rather than the length of the initial list and the depth. (But I'm pretty sure you do still need the depth, to handle the complexity of the `[[[[[[[[[[0]]]]]]]]]]` case, which obviously isn't any function of either the initial length 1 or the final length 1.)

Comment: Thanks for the note on the cost of popping. Is it safe to say that there is not an `O(n)` solution for this? Another question: are you saying the time complexity of the iter_flatten() is the same as function 1, but with better space usage?

Comment: If n is the initial list length, there can't be an `O(n)` solution, given the `[[[[[[[[[[0]]]]]]]]]]` case, where n is 1 but the minimum possible steps are 9. I think the best solution is `O(n*m)` (or, if you use `n` for the final list size instead of initial, `O(n+m)`). I think you can get that with `iter_flatten`, and you can also get that with `flattenIterable` if you use something constant-spliceable like a single-linked list instead of an array. But I'm not sure without thinking about it more.

Comment: That makes sense. Last clarification: the `+ m` in your above equation is coming from the `arr[i: i + 1] = arr[i]` or the `yield e`, is that right?

Comment: @ColinRicardo Slight correction to my explanation of your first algorithm, based on the discussion with abarnert. The other thing is, I consider N to be the number of elements in the final flattened list, and discuss complexity accordingly, so you might see a difference in notation between my answer and abarnert's comments.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. There are N elements, so you will need to visit each element at least once. Overall, your algorithm will run for O(N) iterations. The deciding factor is what happens *per iteration*.

Your first algorithm has 2 loops, but if you observe carefully, it is still iterating over each element O(1) times per iteration. However, as @abarnert pointed out, the `arr[i: i + 1] = arr[i]` moves every element from `arr[i+1:]` up, which is O(N) again.

Your second algorithm is similar, but you are adding lists in this case (in the previous case, it was a simple slice assignment), and unfortunately, list addition is linear in complexity.

In summary, both your algorithms are quadratic.

Comment: Ah, that first sentence makes sense now. With regards your second point, why `O(1)` and not `O(m)` times per iteration?

Comment: @ColinRicardo because you iterate over each element once, to re-assign it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was confusing myself. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: But `arr[i: i + 1] = arr[i]` is not constant time. It moves every element from `[i+1:]` up, which takes `O(n)` moves (and then it copies `len(arr[i]))` values into the now-vacant slots, which takes more than `O(1)` but less than `O(n)`, so I think we can ignore it).

Comment: Plus, I think you're missing the fact that the depth can be arbitrarily high. For example, consider `[[[[[[[[[[0]]]]]]]]]]`. It clearly doesn't take only 1 step to flatten this. Why? Because before you can copy the `0`, you have to copy the `[0]`, and before that you have to copy the `[[0]]`, and so on. So, it's worst-case `O(m)` steps for this step for each element. Put that together with the other point, and the `n` steps that you're counting each take `n+m` times, so it's `O(n**2 + n*m)`, which is just as quadratic as the recursive version.

Comment: @abarnert Interesting... you make some valid points I didn't consider before. Thanks, edited.